# Rails escape all URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, encoding, utf-8

In Rails, I'd like to be able to escape all my URLs using `link_to` across the board. What is the best way to do this?

Currently, the permalinks are stored in UTF-8. e.g. it's stored as: 水-water

I'm running Spree, so I would like to avoid overriding all the template files with CGI.escapes to achieve the same thing.

Other considerations:

- Store the Escaped url in the permalinks column? (params encodes it to UTF-8 and then the sequel can't find it because it was stored in the DB as escaped)

Thanks in advanced!
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, link_to already escapes the UTF-8 properly. It was the browser already interpreting it making me perceive it as unescaped.

Using a Raw HTTP Viewer such as: http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html

Helped see that.